# finishedWithAuth:error: method calling after Google+ authentication in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, google-plus, google-authentication

I already successfully integrated Google+ to my iOS app. But with the latest Apple store updates, the app is not allowed to open the browser to initiate the Google authentication. Therefor I needed to create a web interface inside my application.

So I did that it as follow,

Place where I restrict opening a browser app for auth URL

```
   - (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSLog(@"%s - %d", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__);

    if ([[url absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"googlechrome-x-callback:"]) {

        return NO;

    } else if ([[url absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"]) {

        NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:url forKey:@"authUrl"];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ApplicationOpenGoogleAuthNotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
        return NO;
    }

    return [super openURL:url];
}
```

Inside my ViewController where a user tap on the Google+ Sign In button, I place this observer

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(callInternalWeb:) name:@"ApplicationOpenGoogleAuthNotification" object:nil];
```

This will load a different UIViewController with a UIWebView inside of that

```
   - (void)callInternalWeb:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"%s - %d", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__);

    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"googleAuthSegue" sender:userInfo];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%s - %d", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__);

    GoogleAuthViewController *googleAuthViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    [googleAuthViewController navigateUrl:sender];
}
```

Then inside GoogleAuthViewController, I'm trying to load the UIWebView with the URL that I passed using NSNotification

```
NSString *formatStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",googleAuthUrlStr];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:formatStr];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

_webView.delegate = self;

[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

After Google log in completed I can redirect back to the UIViewController like below

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSLog(@"%s - %d", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__);

    if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"my.bunble.googleplusintegration:/oauth2callback"]) {

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

But I cannot get Google user details because following method is not calling

```
- (void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error {}
```

Earlier I was able to get user details like below inside above mentioned method

```
if ([GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication) {

    GTLPlusPerson *googleUser = [signIn googlePlusUser];

    NSString *firstName = [[googleUser name] givenName];
    NSString *lastName = [[googleUser name] familyName];
    NSString *dob = [googleUser birthday];
    NSString *gender = [googleUser gender];
    NSString *gUserId = [googleUser identifier];
    NSString *gUserEmail = signIn.authentication.userEmail;

    GTLPlusPersonImage *image = [googleUser image];
}
```

How can I get those details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code is completely correct. The missed part is

```
[GPPURLHandler handleURL:[request URL] sourceApplication:@"com.apple.mobilesafari" annotation:nil];
```

So the complete code will look like below

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSLog(@"%s - %d", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__);

    if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"my.bunble.googleplusintegration:/oauth2callback"]) {
    [GPPURLHandler handleURL:[request URL] sourceApplication:@"com.apple.mobilesafari" annotation:nil];

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```